# How to make a variable to do the 'or' operator in if-else statment

Tags: matlab

how to make the 'fcol' to equal to 'icol' or less than 'icol' by 1 or more than 'icol' by 1. The 'fcol' would always equal to 1.

```
icol = 5;
if icol == icol

  fcol = icol || fcol == icol+1 ||  fcol == icol-1
end
```

Comment: Could you explain with some sample values?

Comment: i would like fcol =5 || fcol = 6 || fcol =7

Comment: You said - `"less than 'icol' by 1"`, so shouldn't it be `fcol = 4`?

Comment: oh yes sorry my mistake fcol should also be fcol = 4 not 7

Comment: I don't think you understand what an `if` statement does, or what the or operation `||` does, or what `=` and `==` do, and why they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works for you when put inside the `IF` conditional statement -

```
fcol = ismember(icol,[-1 0 1] + icol)
```

About the code: `[-1 0 1] + icol` creates the comparison operands for checking against `icol` and then `ismember` detects if there is `ANY` match and the decision is set to `fcol`.

---

**Edit:** For generating three random integers within the range `1` from `icol`, use this -

```
randi([icol-1 icol+1],1,3)
```

For generating one such random integer, use this -

```
randi([icol-1 icol+1])
```

Comment: @Dicksontan You might want to edit your question about needing random integer(s), otherwise the solution won't be synced with the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this

```
if fcol== icol || ((icol-fcol)==1) || ((fcol-icol)==1)
{
do this
}
```